# Should SpriteKit games support both portrait and landscape orientations? Or, should they support only one of those orientations?

Tags: ios, iphone

Here's some background:

I was fooling around with SKShapeNode/SKSpriteNode objects by assigning them volume-based SKPhysicsBody objects, and I wrapped their enclosing scene with an edge-based SKPhysicsBody. The objects interact as expected when under the influence of gravity, applied forces, and in-game collisions.

The problem occurs when the simulator's orientation changes. So far, I've been using the .resizeFill value for the scene's scaleMode property. The results of using this value have been inconsistent. The nodes tend to be misplaced or fall out of the scene's bounding SKPhysicsBody edge object.

So, I am wondering if making SpriteKit games for both portrait and landscape is a good idea? Should SpriteKit games be limited to one orientation? I would like to know the general rules (i.e. best practices) for making these decisions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of what you are asking falls under the 'should be closed / too broad' category: basically it depends on what your app needs to do so we can only give opinions.

However to answer one fundamental part: it is perfectly acceptable (and good practice if it fits your desired functionality) to make your app only support one interface orientation.

Comment: I see. Do you find  that Spritekit is inconsistent and "buggy" when trying support both orientations (i.e. nodes being misplaced, the points to pixel ratios changing, etc...)?

Comment: No I don't find that. I have written a couple of apps that use SpriteKit in both orientations. One rescaled the SKScene to fit (and thus had to cope with nodes outside the new bounds and reposition them) the other rescaled the view to fit (and thus everything scaled automatically). You do need to cope with changes but SpriteKit itself I find OK in this area at least.